# Weapons in brand new world reforging on their own?

Tags: terraria

My file was corrupt so I had to start a whole new world.  All the weapons I've forged like a new pick axe is now a demonic pick axe, my staff was demoted so it does less damage than I need it to. Every item in crafting is doing this but I just started a brand new world. Ideas?  Insight?

To clarify... Every single item I craft is modified. I started a new world because my file was corrupted. This modification never happened in my old world but in my new world I can't craft anything without it coming out modified.

Comment: this is very vague, im not even sure what your trying to describe

Answer (score 5):

It's not entirely clear from your question, but I assume that you're seeing these modifiers appear on newly-crafted items. If so, that's normal game behavior. The [Modifier](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Modifier) page in the official wiki states:

> All Weapons and Accessories have a 75% chance (3 in 4) of receiving a random Modifier when crafted, purchased from an NPC, looted from Chests/Crates, or collected from drops.

Comment: Thank you. No Google searches showed this. Every single item I craft with melee is modified in my new world. This never happened to me in my old one. It makes sense to have a chance of modification but every single item? Seemed odd. Thank you for the link.